# deployment issue in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

i'm working on asp.net web application project.Situation is that i want to deploy my project on hosting site but when i try to deploy using vs2010 it get me error saying access denied error 550.

i want to know can i deploy on ftp server using package.

actually when i unzip and copying all the files of package on server using file upload of host server it done but when i run the site it show runtime error.u can see that error on

http://prakash.somee.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `customErrors` as your screen shot is telling you, so you can see what the real error is:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: after changing that i'm getting another error u can see that error on
http://prakash.somee.com/